# Ошибка "Unknown name" при вызове веб-сервис AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

Написал код вызова веб-сервиса. На части компьютеров с установленным IE 11 код работает стабильно и без ошибок, а у большинства не работает, ошибка в сборке jquery-1.3.1.min.js выделяется следующий код в сборке

```
xhr.open(type, s.url, s.async, s.username, s.password)
```

Поставил полную сборку, код ошибки следующий

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Comment: Для начала подключите несжатую jquery, чтобы понятнее было где что не так.

Comment: У тех, кого не работает: какой браузер и какой он версии? Добавьте, пожалуйста, больше подробностей в вопрос

Comment: У всех браузер IE 11, сеть корпоративная, обновления устанавливаются по SMS (windows update).

Comment: @MikhailZhuykov классная версия jquery. ;) Попробуйте поновее версию поставить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо всем за помощь, выяснилось, что url домена отсутствует в trusted zone, добавление все исправило )

Comment: т.е. вы делали кросдоменный rquest ?

Comment: Да...именно кроссдоменный

Comment: тогда все логично, сервер не отдавал корректный заголовок и браузер считал ответ сервера ошибочным

Comment: Все дело в том, что серверы такого же dns-name были добавлены в trusted zone, естественно кроме этого..(((